# Mapbox no longer work with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, leaflet, mapbox

I have been using Mapbox together with Leaflet for quite some time. Recently, the Mapbox maps stopped loading. What happened?

Here's the .js code thats used to load Mapbox's tiles:

```
var map = new L.map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(42.352455, -71.048069),
    zoom: 13,
    maxZoom: 17,
    layers: new L.TileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.mapbox-streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using map tiles hosted in your own account. The `mapbox.mapbox-streets` is no longer valid.

Comment: I signed up for an account but see no way to use the tiles as I did before. Do I need the mapbox js library to use their map tiles? I coded the entire site based on Leaflet.

Comment: Click Publish on the map page, click 'mapbox.js' as your option, copy and paste the map id, and replace `mapbox.mapbox-streets` in your example above with it.